# Grid за пределами экрана

Tags: c#, windows, wpf, разработка-игр

Подскажите, пожалуйста,как сделать так, что бы grid отрисовывался за пределами экрана?
Т.е. мне нужно сделать большой `Grid` значительно больше экрана. И что бы пользователь мог его перетаскивать. 
Я пытался поставить большую ширину в `Grid`, но в таком случае, когда я начинаю перетаскивать `Grid`, то то, что оказывается за пределами экрана как бы обрезается. Т.е. он выглядит так, будто имеет размер экрана(хотя в реальности он имеет ширину 50000 пикселей) Как можно сделать так, что бы `Grid` не обрезало по размерам экрана?

Answer (score 5):

А почему бы не сделать так:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid Width="50000" Height="50000">
        <!-- здесь ваш content -->
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: заработало, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Мб, я вас не совсем понял, но попробуйте установить MinWidth для грида:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="50000" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

как-то так.

Comment: К сожалению не работает. Оно действительно делает ширину 5000, но она обрезается, по ширине окна. Т.е. реально ширина Grida будет выглядить как у экрана. Это легко проверить, елси добавить кнопку которая будет с помочью маржин двигать grid вправо или в лево.

Comment: Вообще, в принципе мне не обязательно, что бы это был grid, может быть и другой контейнер, но мне нужно, что бы этот контейнер растягивал своё содержимое, по своей длинне и ширине. В частности, сейчас обнаружил, что Canvac как рас отрисовывается за пределами экрана, но как на зло он не растягивает содержимое по своим размерам... Может есть какой нибудь другой контейнер который делает и то и то?